# How to hack a battery powered device to use 1 Li-ion cell instead of 2 NiMH cells?

Tags: voltage, lithium-ion, battery-operated, batteries

I want to hack a cordless computer mouse, so it can be used with 1 lithium ion cell (standard cobalt cathode to be extra precise) instead of the intended 2 nickel metal hydride cells.  The main reason for doing this, is to see how well it works.
All cells for this task have to be in the form factor AA (cylindrical, 13,5mm to 14,5mm diameter, 49,2mm to 50,5mm length), because they have to stay in the battery hold without support (glue is not an option).  Lithium cells in this form are pretty expensive IMHO but its for science.

My question is this:  How do I make sure the cell is not discharged too much?

Comment: Use a step down IC with low voltage protection/shutdown.

Comment: A step down would have to be small enough to fit in the battery hold.  And there would have to be enough space left to fit in the real cell.  this might be possible, but I deemed it too impractical.

Comment: A buck ICs are normally soic, tssop, or even smaller leadless packages. All of which are TINY compared to any given AA or AAA sized battery. That is even with all required passive components (normally 3 caps, maybe one inductor, and 3 or so resistors). A buck/step down ic and all require parts can fit in a dime to nickel sized pcb...

Comment: the problem with that is, that it still does not adress the main problem: how to get the voltage supplied by the converter to the mouse?  the terminals are springs made from stainless steel.  i do not want to remove them.  hence a buck is impractical to me.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem I see is this:  The near-empty-voltage (2.5V) of the 1 Li-ion is higher than the near-empty-voltage of 2 NiMH cells (2*0.9V=1.8V), which will likely lead to a damaged cell, because the mouse still drains the cell and does not flash the battery-is-low-led.

My plan to circumvent this, is to use the unused second chamber of the battery holder to install an "adapter cell" consisting of one or more electronic components bridging the chamber and reducing the voltage of the Li-Ion cell so it can be used as if it was 2 NiMH cells.

My first thought was to use simple all-purpose Si-diodes as voltage dependent resistors.  The typical 0.7V drop across is exactly what I need (2.5V-1.8V=0.7V).  But this is not very precise, is it?

[image: my first prototype of the Si-diode adapter cell]

Following an earlier approach to this problem I made the cell depicted above.  Its two Si-diodes in series meant to be used together in a two cell battery hold, where the other cell is an Li-ion cell.  I did not have a chance to test it yet, because I did not want to invest into the cells, but after reading here that it might actually work I ordered 2 cells in the right dimensions.

The adapter cell is made from regular power diodes soldered directly in series to each other and to the terminals of an cut up Ni-Cd cell.  Soldering to the terminals was not easy, since they are made from stainless steel, but with a metal brush and flux it fused well.
The white material is epoxy resin coated gypsum plaster; I used that to give the cell more stability and to have some area to write onto.  It also gives the cell weight, which is important when using it in a mouse.

It almost looks like a real AA cell. :)

[image: A self-made adapter cell with some commercial NiMH cells]

Comment: I think the problem you face is that you are trying to use a series element to stop a voltage falling too low and this voltage (i.e. the battery terminals) you haven't got full access too and if you "swapped compartments" would the circuit still work as intended? Maybe you can find a smaller cell and use the remaining "AA" space for the protection circuits.

Comment: Keep one thing in mind: some mouses (apple for example) can run on either one or two batteries (so you can swap one at a time an never be without power). I'm not sure how it switches between the two; any way this solution wouldn't work on those.

Comment: Be careful if the mouse has a charger dock.  You may well light something on fire if you try to use it...

Comment: We tested the setup with the two diodes and it did not work quite as well as expected: the battery low indicator was blinking even when the cell was still half full.  I removed one diode and now it works very well.  Also using plaster was a stupid idea, I used hot glue after that change.  The mouse has been in use with a Li-ion cell instead of the regular one for over a year now without any ill effect.

Comment: i found a interesting liion battery that does approximately what i  wanted to do in the first place. the downside is, that these cells can not be charged in a regular multi charger:
http://lygte-info.dk/review/batteries2012/Kentli%20AA%202800mWh%20%28Blue%29%20UK.html